# CloudFlare, Nginx, error 520 accessing PDF file

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

We just added our website to CloudFlare and everything runs smoothly till now.

When I'm trying to access a pdf file using the absolute path cloudflare returns error 520, this used to work before cloudflare

does anyone know what can break this?

any nginx tweaks needed?

Answer (score 0):

The "520" error is not a standard status code.

You can troubleshooting the issue with cloudflare support, check here:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error

Comment: after pausing the cloudflare service the file is accessible again.
does it say what is wrong?

Comment: If you don't to analyze the issue, you can may "exclude" this file from CDN, check on the cloudflare docs.